# Level Requirement and Mana cost of affixes

Tags: path-of-exile

I recently found a unique item, which had an affix which is also a gem affix. Like all gem affixes, there is a mana cost and a level requirement listed for the gem type.

- Does the item then have an inherent mana cost due to the affix?
- What equivalent gem level does the affix attach to the item (i.e. lvl 1 or item base level?)
- Does the affix level up like a gem?

I gave it to a party member so I cannot test it.

In this instance: Culling Strike

Comment: `which had an affix which is also a gem affix`...  Huh ?

Comment: e.g. Culling Strike

Comment: There are legendaries out there that provide skills like gems do?  That's news to me.

Comment: Same here; it would worth a word or an example in the question.

Comment: @anto: such as "Culling Strike"? As cited in the question

Comment: I mean: I didn't know there were items with gem's skills/affixes on it -- never seen this before, nor heard of it.  So the question is a bit disturbing, at first glance ;)  From [what I've found on the wiki](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Unique_Items#Axes), I assume the item is either [Kaom's Primacy](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/File:KaomsPrimacy.png) or [Limbsplit](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/File:Limbsplit.png)...

Comment: From what I can see, those legendaries provide a set level of a skill.  Not sure if they can level up or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Culling Strike on an item is not equivalent to the gem, but simply means that item insta-kills mobs below 10% health with no other effects. There is no inherent mana multiplier or leveling that can occur.

There are also item mods which read "gems in this item supported by level x *support gem"* which *will* increase the cost of the supported skills. These effects are constant and do not level up like a gem would.